# Instead of the set of "?" use an array

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

How to make a request without using a lot of characters, and use an array instead of them?

Inside my array `@rowCASHIERGRPs` numbers like "0001,0020,0027,0700";

I tried this but this does not work.

#### First:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBIx::Simple;

my $dbfile='DPTDAT.db';
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:$dbfile", "", "",

my $result = $db->query(
'select b.ID,CASHNUM,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,sum(f6),sum(f7),sum(f8) 
from CKRDATA as a 
inner join CKRDATCASHIERNAME as b 
where a.ID =b.ID and b.CASHNUM =? 
group by f1,b.ID order by b.ID,f1',
@rowCASHIERGRPs);
```

#### Second:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbfile='DPTDAT.db';
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:$dbfile", "", "", {RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1});

my $sqlt = "select b.ID,CASHNUM,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,sum(f6),sum(f7),sum(f8) 
from CKRDATA as a
inner join CKRDATCASHIERNAME as b 
where a.ID = b.ID and b.CASHNUM IN (" .
"join(', ', ('?') x @rowCASHIERGRPs)" .
"group by f1, b.ID order by b.ID, f1";

my $dbqueryAllDataCKR = $db->prepare($sqlt);

$dbqueryAllDataCKR->execute(@rowCASHIERGRPs);
```

Sample data that I want to get:

```
"001""0002"":0000""XXXXXXXX"":00"":0000"":00""0""0""0.0"
"001""0002"":0001""MMMMMMMM"":11"":0000"":00""0""0""0.0"
"001""0002"":0002""YYYYYYYY"":26"":0000"":00""0""0""0.0"
"001""0002"":0009""zzzzzzzz"":01"":0000"":00""0""0""0.0"
"001""0002"":0101""VVVVVVVV"":17"":0086"":00""145""3432""35740099.0"
```

Comment: First, if _none of this does not work_ I guess everything is ok. Second, add some data to your post to ease the examination.

Comment: You're not showing any connects. That code is not going to work. Please show your real code.

Comment: Fixed, I hope..

Comment: Now we're still missing the assignment of `@rowCASHIERGRPs` in your examples. Since you're using SQLite you can nicely give us two programs with example input included that we can copy, paste and run. You're also not saying how you want to get to that output. I'm assuming you are running `sqlite3` and then running your query with values put in manually. That's how you got the output. But since you're not actually using the result of the `execute` in your code, how do you know you're getting the wrong stuff back?

Comment: In what way does it not work? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example doesn't work because you don't terminate the `connect` statement

```
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:$dbfile", "", "",
```

and because `b.CASHNUM = ?` can compare only one value but you are passing a whole array of values

Your second example doesn't work because you have

```
"join(', ', ('?') x @rowCASHIERGRPs)" .
```

inside double quotes, so it will copy that expression instead of building a comma-separated list out of the array values

This may work for you, but you haven't shown any data so I've been unable to test it

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use DBI;

my $dbfile = 'DPTDAT.db';
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:$dbfile", "", "", { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 });

my @row_cashier_grps;

my $placeholders = join(', ', ('?') x @row_cashier_grps);

my $sqlt = <<END_SQL;
SELECT cashier.ID, cashnum, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, SUM(f6), SUM(f7), SUM(f8) 
FROM ckrdata AS data
INNER JOIN ckrdatcashiername AS cashier 
WHERE data.ID = cashier.ID
AND cashier.cashnum IN ($placeholders)
GROUP BY f1, cashier.ID
ORDER BY cashier.ID, F1
END_SQL

my $sth = $db->prepare($sqlt);

$sth->execute(@row_cashier_grps);
```